# Are there denominations which prefer using the name "Yeshu‘a" instead of "Jesus"?

Tags: denomination-survey, name-of-jesus

The original name for Jesus in Hebrew-Aramaic is *yeshu‘a*. This was translated into Greek as *Iēsous* and then via the Latin *Iesus* into German, and eventually into English as *Jesus*.

Since Christians believe that using the name of Jesus/Yeshua in prayer adds authority and power, it could be argued that Christians should be using his original name (Yeshua) or at least something closer to it, rather than the somewhat convoluted translation "Jesus".

- Are there any denominations or Christian groups that use "Yeshua" as opposed to "Jesus"?
- Is there any evidence that other denominations have considered changing their usage from "Jesus" to "Yeshua" and are there any documented reasons why that suggestion was rejected?

Comment: One reason I can think of _not_ to change at this point: It would likely alienate you from people you're trying to minister to by saying/implying that the word they use is "wrong." It would be seen as "holier-than-thou" by many people. Using familiar language when witnessing/ministering can be _very_ important, as evidenced by some missionary stories I've read. [Eternity in their Hearts](http://www.amazon.com/Eternity-Their-Hearts-Startling-Throughout/dp/0830738371/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1321374740&sr=1-1) I recommend for some of these stories.

Comment: Even if you changed to the Aramaic form, you'd still pronounce it completely wrong. The only language you can speak properly with English phonemes is English.

Comment: The *World English Bible: Messianic Edition* (also known as the Hebrew Names Version) renders the name as Yeshua. [Yochanan 1:17](http://ebible.org/hnv/JHN01.htm#V17)

Comment: Very closely related question - [What is the Origin of the Name "Jesus"?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/52022/the-messiahs-name)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Christians, in general, do not believe that Jesus' name is 'magic', in the sense that if you say the word your prayer is somehow more effective. The exact version of the name used is not therefore important. "In my name", as Jesus says, can mean a number of things including "with my authority" and "in accordance with my wishes".

It's true that Yeshua is probably a better rendition of the original name than Jesus. However the confusion of changing it - unless you have a good reason - would probably outweigh the advantages.

The only denomination that I know of that uses Yeshua on a regular basis are the Messianic Jews, particularly [Jews for Jesus](http://www.jewsforjesus.ca/messiah.aspx). That's because the name Yeshua is already familiar to many of them, so it isn't nearly as much of a disconnect. It also emphasizes Jesus' Jewishness.

Comment: It's the difference between translation and transliteration. My name, in Polish is Yashu, I think. In Spanish it would be Juan. But in english it's John. There's a direct correspondence, equivalency between all three though, and that's what counts for translation.

Comment: Non-Jewish Hebrew Roots type groups also commonly use more original language type names.